# Adding typescript import prevents compiling to a single js file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, typescript

I am use grunt-typescript to generate a single js file from a set of ts files. This works fine until I add an import statement to one of the ts files.

Example grunt-typescript config

```
    typescript: {
        server: {
            src: ["./ts/file1.ts", "./ts/file2.ts"],
            dest: "./js/out.js",
            options: {
                module: 'amd', //or commonjs
                target: 'es5', //or es3
                basePath: '',
                sourcemap: false,
                declaration: false,
                ignoreError: false
            }
        }
    }
```

If I add an import statement to the top of file2.ts e.g.

```
import PG = require("pg");
```

Then I get errors that code in File1.ts can't find types defined in File2.ts and I get an unexpected File2.js generated in the /ts directory ignoring the dest file parameter. The import seems to cause it to compile File2.ts totally separately.

Is this to be expected with import or how can I fix this to create the expected single js file without compile errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you import an AMD module, or export from outside of any internal module, your file will be compiled as an AMD module.  AMD and single-file compilation are inherently different modes of working and don't like to be mixed.  To read up on internal vs external modules check out [this TypeScript wiki page](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript).

You technically can still import AMD modules using the standard JavaScript method, but it's awkward.  For example, using the [require.d.ts](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/requirejs/require.d.ts) file from DefinitelyTyped:

```
/// <reference path="require.d.ts"/>

require(["somemodule"], (SomeModule: namespace.SomeModule) => {
    // async code called after the module is retrieved
});
```

Without the `import` keyword TypeScript does nothing about the require and leaves you on your own.

Alternately I would recommend going full AMD.  If any of your libraries are AMD it's easier to work with, and you can still [compile down to a single file](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) when it's time to release.